# Ubuntu provides Certificates?

Tags: application-development

I want to know if Ubuntu provides certificates to commercial applications?

Example:
"Appname Certified by Ubuntu"

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Do you mean does Canonical provide SSL certs for apps in their software center? In that case, that would be no. What is your reason for wanting this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no software certification is available from ubuntu . But if you want to sell your app via software center , It must be verified by canonical(via myapps portal)